# Ping times keep oscillating on Wi-Fi: Boom network load?

Tags: network, wifi, airport, ping

I have a 2012 retina MacBook Pro that lags in a very specific way: I have normal ping times for about 5 seconds and then they spike to 100-300ms more than normal for about 5 seconds, and back and forth. Example:

```
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=844 ttl=58 time=5.694 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=845 ttl=58 time=5.508 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=846 ttl=58 time=6.203 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=847 ttl=58 time=6.665 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=848 ttl=58 time=6.074 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=849 ttl=58 time=7.480 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=850 ttl=58 time=54.219 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=851 ttl=58 time=101.125 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=852 ttl=58 time=144.924 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=853 ttl=58 time=188.527 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=854 ttl=58 time=5.604 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=855 ttl=58 time=5.553 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=856 ttl=58 time=9.515 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=857 ttl=58 time=5.364 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=858 ttl=58 time=16.086 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=859 ttl=58 time=8.182 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=860 ttl=58 time=28.378 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=861 ttl=58 time=27.358 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=862 ttl=58 time=73.504 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=863 ttl=58 time=119.722 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=864 ttl=58 time=174.853 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.192.46: icmp_seq=865 ttl=58 time=210.945 ms
```

And so on. It does this at home and at work, and plugging into ethernet via thunderbolt does not exhibit these behaviors. I don't have corresponding spikes in CPU usage so I'm unsure of how to track this issue down.

Please help!

EDIT:

After doing a binary search of killing apps, I have discovered that killing the [Boom 2](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/index.php) app causes the spikes to go away, which is strange because I wouldn't figure that an audio enhancement app would have anything to do with the network. It's not sending or receiving bytes according to Activity Monitor, but merely *being active* somehow causes ping times to fluctuate in this manner **only on wifi**. Anybody have an inkling of why this might be the case?

Comment: Mail the developer an url to this post, might be he can help out. Btw, I remember that one of the first Macintosh computers had an issue with the speaker positioned too close to the HD. When playing loud music the drive would have read and write errors due to the magnetic field. Are you playing music when this occurs ;) ?

Comment: Hah! Wouldn't that be funny. But no, I wasn't playing any music when I got those posted pings. I've cross-posted to their forums http://www.globaldelight.com/globaldelightforum/discussion/1887/boom-2-causes-network-ping-times-to-oscillate/p1

Comment: Look at this similar problem: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191485/22003 . The analysis isn't complete but might help you find the function which does load the wireless environment.

Comment: That's it exactly! I've turned it off and will do some testing later.